# Usage of the term 風吹き

Tags: fantasy

In the below passage, I'd like to understand the meaning and nuance of the term "風吹き".

> こんど崖下の刀鍛冶に弟子入りするつもりだ。崖下に**風吹き**から入りなおすんだよ。それで、いずれは一番鎚を打つよ。

Doing some online searches it seems that "風吹き" can mean "wanderer", however this doesn't fit with the context, since it seems the blacksmith speaking is going to leave his current position (as a apprentice) and work under a new master who is a swordsmith.

Comment: Do you mean 風吹{かざふき}きがらす（烏{からす}） for the meaning of "wanderer"?

Comment: @sazarando: Yes, I think that was it. Since there is no 烏 here I guess it is a different meaning.

Comment: It can be written without the Kanji too, so I just thought I would check with you. I think fefe has got it right though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just guessing:

As the man is going to leave his current position and work under a new master as an apprentice, he is going to learn swordsmith from the very beginning, which is "blowing the wind (for the stove)" (風吹き)

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. Would you mind looking at my follow up question I added after "EDIT" above? Thanks

Comment: @Locksleyu I think you should ask a separate question, as the follow up is unrelated to the original.